# Problems with formdata send via Adobe Reader to a php-script

Tags: php, pdf, adobe-reader

I have created a PDF with Adobes LifeCycle and added some forms and a button to send the formdata to a php-script. On the serverside i grab the postdata and store them into a database. No problem so far, but the Adobe Reader now complains about an error something to do with the content of the text/html type.

Here is the error message in german:

> Beim Senden ist ein Fehler
>   aufgetreten. Inhalt des Typs text/html
>   kann nicht verarbeitet werden.

and in english:

> An error occurred during the submit process. Cannot process content of type text/html.

Do i have to write some data in the output of the php-script so the reade knows everthing is okay?

Comment: can you translate that error message for us please?  It sounds like your supposition is correct. I'll bet Reader is looking for some sort of response.

Comment: so, added error message in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, i have to set the content-type to application/pdf and read out a thank-you pdf :). Now the Adobe Reader stops complaining and i have a kind of feedback to the user...

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is respond with application/vnd.fdf with a message.
The following the java code but it has the sample fdf to send a message back
to Acrobat Reader.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");

if (userAgent.toUpperCase().startsWith("ACROFORMS")){
  response.setContentType "application/vnd.fdf");
  out.println("%FDF-1.2\n"+"1 0 obj<< /FDF << /Status (Form has been submitted!) >>      >>endobj\n"+
"trailer\n"+
"<< /Root 1 0 R >>%%\n");

}else
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks, mv288. This code snippet was very useful for me. I used it in a my PDF forms test page.

Answer (score 0):

return value in the AspnetMvc

```
String userAgent = Request.Headers["user-agent"];

            if (userAgent.ToUpper().StartsWith("ACROFORMS"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.fdf";
                Response.Write("%FDF-1.2\n" + "1 0 obj<< /FDF << /Status (Form has been submitted!) >>      >>endobj\n" +
               "trailer\n" +
               "<< /Root 1 0 R >>%%\n");
            }
```